# How can we Remove the action column in List View

Tags: visualforce, list-view

I have one list view in my org and  there are 10 records but I want to remove action column in that list view can you please give me suggestion regarding this

Answer (score 3):

Action column in the List view and in Related list are always visible until and unless we customize the list with visualforce.

[image: Action column]

If user doesn't have Edit and Delete permissions then those links will not be displayed, but we will see the blank column then.

Answer (score 0):

1. If your listview on object only then you have to remove the edit,delete permission for the profile so they cannot change or delete the listview record but problem is this column header will show and all the rows particular row will show blank.

2.. If you want to show in visualforce page then you have to add apex:listviews tag.

```
  <apex:page>
    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"/>

   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#globalHeaderBar").css('display','none');
        $(".bPageHeader").css('display','none');
        $(".handlebarContainer").css('display','none');
        $(".bPageFooter").css('display','none');
        $(".fFooter").css('display','none');
        $(".listHeader").css('display','none');
        $(".actionColumn").css('display','none');
    });
</script>        
        <apex:listViews type="Your Object API name here"/>
</apex:page>
```